# Codeigniter highcharttable count how many data in a month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, charts, highcharts

I have this `project` table that u can see below, from the table below I want to make a chart that contains how many `project` in that month

```
id | project_name | start_date |
1  | proj1        | 2017-09-01 | 
2  | proj2        | 2017-09-01 |
3  | proj3        | 2017-09-01 |
4  | proj4        | 2017-08-01 | 
5  | proj5        | 2017-08-01 |
```

what I have done so far is make an model, and then I was confuse what should I do next as the model that I created is not dynamic, it only reads a certain month which is in this case `month`=`09`

```
public function get_monthly_totals($theYear = '', $theMonth = '')
{
    $select = "
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS start_count
        FROM
           project
        WHERE 
           MONTH(start_date)=09";
    return $this->db->query($select);
}
```

[image]

I want to make a chart like above and the plugin that I use is **highcharttable** which is convert the html table data into a chart, how I make something like that, how I make a month still exist even though there is no data in it and also how to connect the data into the right month?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it by doing something like this in my controller, I know it's not beautiful but it is fine for now

```
public function dashboard_project()
{   
    $thn = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $id = md5($this->session->userdata('id'));
    $data['rows'] = $this->pengguna_m->getPengguna($id)->row();

    $data['januari'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('01',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['februari'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('02',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['maret'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('03',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['april'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('04',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['mei'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('05',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['juni'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('06',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['juli'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('07',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['agustus'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('08',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['september'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('09',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['november'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('10',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['oktober'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('11',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['desember'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('12',$thn)->num_rows();

    $data['title']= 'Aplikasi Saranabudi';
    $data['aktif']  = 'Jumlah Kategori Project';
    $data['judul_hal']= 'Dashboard Kategori Project';

    $this->load->view('layout/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('layout/sidebar',$data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/pelanggan/home');
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple syntax to count per month within a year

```
public function get_monthly_totals($theYear = ''){
    $select = "
        SELECT 
          COUNT(*) AS start_count,
          MONTH(start_date) as month
        FROM
           project
        WHERE 
           YEAR(start_date)='$theYear'
        GROUP BY
           MONTH(start_date)
    ";
    return $this->db->query($select);
}
```